# Using Netplan to setup a static IP for a cluster of devices connected via ethernet

Tags: network-manager, raspberrypi, netplan

I'm coming from NetworkManager world, so bear with me. I can do this on Ubuntu if I change Netplan's rendered to `NetworkManger`, but I'm hoping to learning the more native approach.

I have four devices (Raspberry Pi's) running Ubunutu 20.04 connected by switch. Only the 'master' pi connects to the external net via wifi, the rest have a static internal IP, and connect outside via NAT from the master.

With NetworkManager, i can `vim /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0` and add:

```
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.0.0.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 10.0.0.255
    gateway 10.0.0.1
```

before installing/configuring isc-dhcp server. Everything works gravy. I'm having trouble translating this into the net-plan configuration yaml. Or does it also involve Networkd??

Comment: What have you tried so far in your Netplan configuration?  It's important to see what you're trying to do with Netplan or what you've tried.  This involves configuring Netplan which tells NetworkD how to configure things.  See https://netplan.io/examples/#using-dhcp-and-static-addressing and the second section of that subsection for how to configure static IPs with Netplan.

Comment: Also, NetworkManager on `/etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0` is NOT NetworkManager, it's `ifupdown`.  Network Manager wouldn't use the `/etc/network/interfaces...` to configure IPs ;)

Comment: Also it is incorrect, in any network configuration tool, to have your address and gateway set to the same value

Comment: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-configure-static-ip-address-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux#h6-2-configure-static-ip-address-using-netplan